# Use an array of class objects that are actually lists

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, .net-core

I need to figure out how to declare an array and each object in the array is a list of another object.

So the structure would be something like:

```
myArray[0] = List<MyObject>();
myArray[1] = List<MyObject>();
```

MyObject has 3 parts:

```
int anId;
string firstName;
string LastName;
```

How do I declare this and intialize this properly? I am open to other ideas.

Comment: `var someFunkyArray = new List<SomeObject>[10];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An array of List in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464724/an-array-of-list-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to declare it is like this:

```
var array = new List<MyObject>[10];
```

That declares the array. However, it starts out as an array of null references. You have to set them.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) array[i] = new List<MyObject>();
```

Or, if you want to do it all in one go, you can do something clever, like this:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select( x => new List<MyObject>() ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var items = new List<MyObject>[4];
items[0] = new List<MyObject>();
items[1] = new List<MyObject>();
items[2] = new List<MyObject>();
items[3] = new List<MyObject>();
```

or this:

```
List<MyObject>[] items = {
    new List<MyObject>(),
    new List<MyObject>(),
    new List<MyObject>(),
    new List<MyObject>()
};
```

But I wonder if you really want this:

```
var items = new List<List<MyObject>>();
items.Add(new List<MyObject>);
items.Add(new List<MyObject>);
items.Add(new List<MyObject>);
items.Add(new List<MyObject>);
```